# Maximum value of $s = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + v_0t+s_0$

Tags: derivatives, applications

> Height of body moving vertically is $s = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + v_0t+s_0$, where $g>0$, $s$ is metres and $t$ is time in seconds, I am trying to find the maximum height it will reach.

Through derivatives, I understand that to find maximum height, I need to find the critical points of $s$ and evaluate the function at its critical points. To do that, I need to find the first derivative of $s$ and set it equals to $0$.

The derivative of $s' =-\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + v_0t$, from here, how to I find the maximum height which will actually be $\frac{(v_0)^2}{2g} + s_0$, did I differentiate the wrong term? I do not understand

Comment: Your derivative itself is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, at the time of maximum height, the velocity is zero. We can determine that time by solving
$$
-gt + v_0 = 0 \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{v_0}{g}.
$$

The corresponding height is then given by
$$
- \frac 12 g \frac{v_0^2}{g^2} + v_0 \frac{v_0}{g} + s_0 = \frac{v_0^2}{2g} + s_0.
$$